# ¿Como iterar un JSON en c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy consumiendo un API y lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void GetTrafficByDay(string token)
    {
        var urlCompleta = GlobalCharlesAndKeith.APP_URL_HOST + GlobalCharlesAndKeith.APP_NAME + "/api" + "/traffic" + "/day/" + Global.date;

        using (var client = new RestClient(urlCompleta))
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(urlCompleta, Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.ToString());

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(response.Content);
                foreach (var listStore in json)
                {
                    if(listStore.store == "Chales y Keith - Artz Pedregal")
                    {
                        foreach(var traffic in listStore.traffic)
                        {
                           //Aqui me arroja el error
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

-Lo que quiero hacer es obtener uno por uno los registros que se encuentran en `listStore.traffic`, pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Comó puedo recorrer de manera correcta ese arreglo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son mi modelos que utilizo:

```
public class Root
{
    public string store { get; set; }
    public Traffic traffic { get; set; }
}

public class Traffic
{
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-09T01:00:00")]
    public int _T010000 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2023-04-09T02:00:00")]
    public int _T020000 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2023-04-09T03:00:00")]
    public int _T030000 { get; set; }

    ....
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-09T00:00:00")]
    public int _T000000 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hay una clase llamada `JObject`, creo que con esa podrías hacer lo que quieres hacer. No la conozco muy bien...

Comment: Para iterar algo, debe ser IEnumerable o una Lista. en tu caso, Traffic es un objeto individual y pues, está lejos de ser una lista. Edita la pregunta, agrega el JSON que tienes y seguro alguien te ayuda a resolver el asunto, está sencillo el tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en `listStore.traffic` que es de tipo `Traffic` en tu modelo, pero estás intentando iterar sobre él como si fuera una lista.

Para recorrer los registros en `listStore.traffic`, necesitas acceder a las propiedades de `Traffic` que contienen los valores. Se puede usar la reflexión para obtener las propiedades de `Traffic` y luego iterar sobre ellas para obtener los valores:

```
foreach (var listStore in json)
{
    if (listStore.store == "Chales y Keith - Artz Pedregal")
    {
        var trafficProperties = typeof(Traffic).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in trafficProperties)
        {
            int trafficValue = (int)property.GetValue(listStore.traffic);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + property.Name + ", Valor: " + trafficValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @jaracoder, tu solución fue mucho mejor a la que ya habia implementado, primero estaba haciendo una lista y luego implementaba el foreach. Pero la tuya es mucho mejor, muchas gracias.